# pass C# parameters to JS

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a C#-MVC project. I want to refresh the page every X second -
I put in the cshtml file the code:

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
   timedRefresh(X);
</script>
```

but I need to take X from C#, let's say it's "ViewBag.Seconds".
How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Razor doesn't care if it's outputting HTML or javascript, so you could do:

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
   timedRefresh(@(ViewBag.Seconds));
</script>
```

Comment: thanks! I tried
    <script type="text/JavaScript">
       timedRefresh(@ViewBag.Seconds);
   </script>
 and it didn't work.. so I asked here :)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the Razor syntax it can be done like this:

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
  timedRefresh(@(ViewBag.Seconds));
</script>
```

The IntelliSense may report an error or warning, but it works anyway.

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty easy

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
   timedRefresh(@ViewBag.Seconds);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an Action too.
like this:

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
   timedRefresh(@(Html.Action("Action","Controller")));
</script>
```