# How to pass value from cshtml file to the JS

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

Hello I need to pass one param to the my JS function after pressing button.

Here is my button:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="UserClick" onclick="foo(@HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name)">Click here to add me as a user</button>
```

as You can see I try to send `@HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name` to the function foo.

Here my Foo function:

```
    function foo(value) {
         alert(value);
    };
```

I tried sollutions from those topics:
[One](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419718/html-apostrophe)
[Two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10296302/pass-c-sharp-parameters-to-js)

But all I get get is this error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
```

How to bypass this?

@update

All files included:

```
<script src="/Scripts/CreateDevice.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
```

full JS file:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

function foo(value) {
    alert(value);
};
})
```

I can access to the js file from page-source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all change you sequence of file to

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/CreateDevice.js"></script>
```

Declare your function outside document-ready handler. Like

```
$(document).ready(function () {
});

function foo(value) {
    alert(value);
};
```

Pass your parameter in quotes

```
onclick="foo('@HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name');"
```

---

**Additionally,** You can bind event using [**.on()**](http://api.jquery.com/on/)  and pass parameter using attributes

*JS*

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //Bind Event
    $(document).on('click', '#UserClick', function(){
        alert($(this).data('user-name'))
    });
});
```

*HTML*

```
<button type="button" 
    class="btn btn-default" 
    id="UserClick" 
    data-user-name="@HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name"
    >Click here to add me as a user</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
onclick="foo('@HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name');"


$(document).ready(function () {

window.foo = function(value) {
    alert(value);
};
})
```

this will work...

You should consider removing the 'onclick' attribute in the html though, and binding the function to the button using jquery's  [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) function.

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: foo is not defined  after this change

Comment: function foo(value) {
         alert(value);
    };    -- where did you write this ? the browser can't reach this code it seems